# how to get the number of arguments supplied to a lisp function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

How can I get the number of arguments supplied to a Lisp function like in bash with the variable $0?  (I saw a similar question but it does not give the answer.)

Comment: Do you know how to define a function that takes a variable number of arguments?  The simplest function definitions don't, so there's no question about how many arguments were passed.  If you learn how to define variable-argument functions, it will be easy to figure out how to determine how many arguments were passed.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking, but in Common Lisp you can use an `&rest` argument to collect an indeterminate number of arguments into a list.  Using `length` you can see how many were provided.  For instance:

```
CL-USER> (defun numargs (&rest arguments)
           (length arguments))
NUMARGS
CL-USER> (numargs 1 2 3)
3
CL-USER> (numargs 1 2 3 4 5)
5
CL-USER> (numargs)
0
```

Since the question has the [sbcl](/questions/tagged/sbcl) tag, you might be interested in SBCL-specific solutions.  `sb-introspect:function-lambda-list` looks relevant:

```
CL-USER> (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list 'cons)
(SB-IMPL::SE1 SB-IMPL::SE2)
CL-USER> (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list 'numargs)
(&REST ARGUMENTS)
```

If you examine the lambda list, you can determine how many arguments a function can take.